# How do I make disable-for-touch work in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: touch, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a site that another designer built: http://bigbolts.qa.aztekhq.com/. The products in the New Products and Recently Viewed areas on that page have two buttons with tooltips on them, and when they are clicked, they are supposed to trigger other link events: "More Information" goes to the detail page, "Add To Cart" triggers a modal. This works fine on desktops, but not on touch devices. On my iPhone and iPad, touching the links only triggers the tooltips and nothing else. I added data-options="disabled-for-touch:true" to the links, but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

foundation makes it easy to disable or enable on touch-enabled devices, just add class= "show-for-touch" or "hide-for-touch" to the element you want to disable. code example below.

```
<p class="panel">
  <strong class="show-for-touch">You are on a touch-enabled device.</strong>
  <strong class="hide-for-touch">You are not on a touch-enabled device.</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: I was really hoping there would be a way to keep the modal behavior on touch devices. The point of that section is to allow people to add items directly to their cart from the homepage, as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Ahem... according to the [tooltips documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html), it is better to add `data-options="disable_for_touch:true"` to your link. Like this:

```
<span data-tooltip data-options="disable_for_touch:true" class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome!">
    Your Cart
</span>
```

Comment: I will try that, but the site was built in Foundation 4 and I'm pretty sure your citation is for Foundation 5.

Comment: Nope, changing the hyphens to underscores did not make any difference.